# SQL Database scripting table changes

Tags: sql-server-2005, automation

I'm working on a project where we are updating client databases from older version to newer versions of the database and the related schema.

I'm looking for a way do the following for all of the tables in the database that our program uses.

```
If the table doesn't exist
  create table
else
  for each column in the table
    bring the column up to date or create it
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this through management studio and I haven't turned anything up through Google.

Something that would either give me this option in SQL Management Studio or a program that would generate the scripts for me would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tools like [RedGates SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/) or [Apex SQLDiff](http://wwww.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) to compare and sync your schemas. It will compare the old and new database and generate the script for you.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with DaniSQL's suggestions. But I would also add that this is something you can do via PowerShell and using SQLPSX would make it less difficult.